# Responding to a share with React Native Share Menu

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native-share menu to add my app as a target for file shares.

https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu

Everything works great in both iOS and Android in terms of integration with the OS and receiving the information in the app.

My problem is how to show an interim screen which allows the user to choose what to do with the file. If I make the logic part of the home screen it works great, but if the user already had the app open on a different screen, they don't see the share component until they return to the home screen.

I want to respond to the share by showing a new screen, but also allow that screen to navigate to other screens based on the user's choice of action (i.e. so the other screens have to exist in the navigation stack)

Has anyone had a similar experience with this library and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I also have the same issue currently. May be you should post this question on his GutHub repo

Comment: @Manu Check out my answer below. I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I solved it by using a "useShare" hook I made and I called the hook from my home screen.

// sharedHooks.js

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import ShareMenu from "react-native-share-menu";


const useShare = (navigate) => {
    
    const handleShare = useCallback(async (item) => {
        if (!item || !item.data) {
            return;
        }

        const { data } = item;

       // do stuff with data and get ready to navigate

        navigate('SomeOtherComponent', {
            var1,
            data,
            anotherParam
        });

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        ShareMenu.getInitialShare(handleShare);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = ShareMenu.addNewShareListener(handleShare);

        return () => {
            listener.remove();
        };
    }, []);

}

export {
    useShare,
};
```

And then I call it from the home screen like so:

// Home.js

```
// Other imports
import { useShare } from './sharedHooks';

// Other code
export default (props) => {

  const { navigate } = props.navigation

  // Other code
  useShare(navigate);

}
```

And that's it. It will navigate to wherever `SomeOtherComponent` takes it.

The first `useEffect` in sharedHooks.js allows you to receive the data if the app hasn't been opened previously. The second useEffect that calls `const listener = ShareMenu.addNewShareListener(handleShare);` will listen for shared events after your app has been opened. Technically you can use these functions within the home screen itself but I prefer to abstract it away in its own file since I have a lot of other things going on before I navigate.

I hope this helps